# Fire event on wheel scroll only once js

Tags: javascript

IMPORTANT: I do know how to detect whether the scroll is up or down (and there are some similar answered questions on this website as well), but I don't know how to do the following: I want to perform some func on whether the wheel scroll is up or down; I have the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel',wheel);
    function wheel(e){
        delta = e.deltaY;
        if (delta > 0) {
            Func1();
        } else  {
            Func2();
        }
    }
```

But with this code the functions are being called all the time while the wheel event continues, while I just simply need to call them once every time a new wheel event happens. how can I go around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated to support multiple scrolls in the same direction and called each function immediately when we start scrolling)

You could save the state:

```
var scrollingDirection = 0; //idle
var lastScroll = 9999;
var scrollIdleTime = 300; // time interval that we consider a new scroll event
window.addEventListener('wheel',wheel);
function wheel(e){
    var delta = e.deltaY;
    var timeNow = performance.now();
    if (delta > 0 && ( scrollingDirection != 1 || timeNow > lastScroll + scrollIdleTime) ) {
        Func1();
        scrollingDirection = 1;
    } else if (delta < 0 && ( scrollingDirection != 2 || timeNow > lastScroll + scrollIdleTime)) {
        Func2();
        scrollingDirection = 2;
    }
    lastScroll = timeNow;
}
```

Comment: but what if I can go down or up multiple times?

Comment: Fraddy's response doesn't trigger the function at the moment of scroll. If you need them to be called the moment you start scrolling in a certain direction, I've amended my solution to make use of the time in between scrolls. This way you get multiple triggers for one direction (as long as the time in scrollIdleTime has passed since the last scroll) and they're called as soon as you start scrolling, which in my opinion is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add delay in executing your function of around 300 ms. After timeout if still event is occurring then set new timeout by clearing older one.

Check below snippet.

```
var wheel_timer = 0

window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(wheel_timer);
    wheel_timer = setTimeout(function () {
        wheel(e)
    }, 10)
});

function wheel(e) {
    delta = e.deltaY;
    if (delta > 0) {
        Func1();
    } else {
        Func2();
    }
}
```

One suggestion can be instead of using `wheel` event you can you `scroll` event.

**Edit**: Improved answer to give a immediate response.

Comment: seems to be working better than the other solutions as I can go in one direction multiple times without double scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scrolled = true;
window.addEventListener('wheel',wheel);
    function wheel(e){
    if(scrolled == true){
    scrolled = false
        delta = e.deltaY;
        if (delta > 0) {
            Func1();
        } else  {
            Func2();
        }
    }
   }
    function Func1(){
    console.log('1'+ scrolled);
    }
    
    function Func2(){
    console.log('2' + scrolled)
    }
```

you can do this by adding an if-else block inside your scroll function,

as per my snippet above, the variable `scrolled` is by default set as `true` and when you make a scroll `scrolled` variable become false so for the second time it won't again enter in if block.